# Automatically align checkboxes in a bootstrap inline form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the [following code](http://bootply.com/98180):

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Form one</legend>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input1">Input1</label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="input1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input2">Input2</label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="input2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input3">Input3</label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="input3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="input4">Input4</label>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="input4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Form 2</legend>
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input5">Input5</label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="input5">                                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input6">Input6</label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="input6">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input7">Input7</label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                           <input type="checkbox" id="input7">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input8">Input8</label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="input9">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </fieldset>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

( I am sorry for the poor identation, but i posted a link to bootply also). I want the inputs of the first form to appear two at each row, so it must look like this for form 1

```
Input1 input2 
input3 input4
```

and

```
Input5 Input6
Input7 Input8
```

for form 2 in the second collumn. I set up two collumns both of them using col-md-6 class and in each collumn i am placing the fields. But even with setting two sub collumns of 3 I can't get the result I want. What am i doing wrong? I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: Did you not want to use `Input8`?

Comment: Yes edited. I see where I am wrong, i set the column to 6 units, so in order to have two subcollumns I must set them to 6 again.Right?

Comment: Yes, I think so (if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [something like this](http://bootply.com/98183)

I changed `col-md-3` to `col-md-6`.

If I didn't understand correctly, just tell me.

Comment: Yes that's what i commented on prev post. But how can i deal with word wrap, if an input label is to big it will wrap and the checkbox will appear underneath it. If i change col-md-6 to 7 e.g then everything goes one checkbox each-collumn. Can this be solved, meaning if i have a checkbox with big label, then it won't wrap it, it will take as much space it needs and then every other checkbox will appear under it or next ot it (if enough space). Do I make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to clear the float at each point where you want to begin a new block. For example, like this:

```
  <div style="clear:both;"><div></div></div>
```

Here is the modified code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Form one</legend>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1">Input1</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="input1" type="checkbox">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input2">Input2</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="input2" type="checkbox">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"><div></div></div>        
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input3">Input3</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="input3" type="checkbox">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input4">Input4</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="input4" type="checkbox">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>      
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"><div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Form 2</legend>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input5">Input5</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input id="input5" type="checkbox">
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input6">Input6</label>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="input6" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"><div></div></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input7">Input7</label>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="input7" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="input8">Input8</label>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="input9" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry I added an extra float clear in there. I removed the one before the second form. You can see the result here: http://bootply.com/98188

Comment: Thank you....I have to deal with word wrap now (see comment on lower post). The thing is that I am placing the fields automatically, using django and a for loop and I was looking for an autoated procedure.

Comment: @Apostolos for your labels and inputs to appear on the same line, you'd want to change the input's display to inline or inline-block. Is that what you mean?